# How can you execute initialization before powershell script execution?

Tags: powershell

How can you execute something on any powershell initialization.
I want to execute some commands before the execution of any powershell script.

I'm looking for something similar to `.bash_profile` or `.bash_rc` but for powershell.

Comment: Without more information, I gather you're looking for Powershell Profile. Info from [TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx) and [GSX](http://www.gsx.com/blog/bid/81096/Enhance-your-PowerShell-experience-by-automatically-loading-scripts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Windows PowerShell using`Profiles` to run a specific script whenever powershell is invoked. It is quite similar to `.bahrc`

Following stackoverflow link contains a good explanation of PowerShell profiles.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670891/how-to-install-and-configure-powershell